# Display FNumber (aperture) as a number versus a fraction

Tags: php

I'm a newbie at even trying to work with PHP, but thinking there may be a simple solution to this.  EXIF exposure data is only displaying an "s", so there must be an error.

I'd also like to display FNumber as "Aperture" with common f-stop, such as "f2.8", but it shows a fraction 28/10.  Is there PHP code that can be inserted directly to the template file to convert this?  In Wordpress image.php, there is code for simplifying fractions, but these values are not being passed through the file - they are being modified directly in the template file.  There's definitely something wrong with this...

```
<dt>EXIF data:</dt>
<dd><ul>
<?php foreach ($exif as $key => $value): 
    if (($key != "Width") && ($key != "Height") && ($key !="DateTime")): ?><li><strong><?php
        if ($key == "model") { 
            echo "Camera"; 
        } elseif ($key == "ExposureTime") { 
            echo "Exposure"; 
            $newvalue = explode("(", $value);
            $newvalue = substr($newvalue[2], 0, -1)."s";
        } elseif ($key == "FNumber") { 
            echo "Aperture"; 
        } else { 
            echo $key; 
        } ?></strong>: <?php if (!$newvalue) { echo $value; } else { echo $newvalue; $newvalue = ''; } ?></li>
    <?php endif; 
endforeach; ?>
</ul></dd></dl>
```

Here is the var_export($exif) info:

```
array (
  'Model' => 'Canon EOS 30D',
  'DateTime' => '2006:12:23 08:35:02',
  'ExposureTime' => '1/100',
  'FNumber' => '28/10',
  'ExposureProgram' => 3,
  'ISOSpeedRatings' => 200,
  'ExifVersion' => '0221',
  'ApertureValue' => '194698/65536',
  'ExposureBiasValue' => '-1/3',
  'MeteringMode' => 5,
  'FocalLength' => '70/1',
)
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump()` of `$exif` for us?

Comment: dump is above - you can see that the array values are what appear to be just the raw data, unformatted.  It would be great to get the FNumber to f/2.8 instead of 28/10 and ExposureTime to 1/100sec (instead of 1/100) - just add the "sec" to the output (somehow).

Comment: Thanks for the var_export() it was extremely helpful. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is appropriate to do so, you can change your code to this:

```
<dt>EXIF data:</dt>
<dd><ul>
<?php foreach ($exif as $key => $value): 
    if (($key != "Width") && ($key != "Height") && ($key !="DateTime")): ?><li><strong><?php
        if ($key == "model") { 
            echo "Camera"; 
        } elseif ($key == "ExposureTime") { 
            echo "Exposure"; 
            //$newvalue = explode("(", $value);
            //$newvalue = substr($newvalue[2], 0, -1)."s";
              $newvalue = $value . "s"; // see note 1
        } elseif ($key == "FNumber") {
            echo "Aperture";
            $fraction_parts = explode("/", $value);
            $newvalue = $fraction_parts[0] / $fraction_parts[1] // see note 2
        } else { 
            echo $key; 
        } ?></strong>: <?php if (!$newvalue) { echo $value; } else { echo $newvalue; $newvalue = ''; } ?></li>
    <?php endif; 
endforeach; ?>
</ul></dd></dl>
```

I didn't test it, so please let me know if it doesn't work and i'll fix it.

**Note 1**
it was only outputting the "s" for the shutter speed because the expode was trying to break the string apart based on `(` but there was not a `(` in the string. So, when the `substr()` function was looking at `newvalue[2]` it wasn't getting anything. Also, you were probably getting a warning from PHP that an array key did not exist (you can check it in your PHP logs).

Since your data from the dump you provided looks like fine output already, I just appended "s" to it.

**Note 2**
To get the decimal value of the fraction I exploded it by "/" which made an array with the numerator as the first value and the denominator as the second value. Then, since `$newvalue` is set to print (instead of `$value`) if it exists, I set `$newvalue` to the result of dividing the numerator by the denominator.

I hope this helps.

Cheers!

**Edit 1**
To get it to show as "sec" instead of "s", just change where the code says `. "s"` to say `. "sec"`. Then, to get it to show "f/" in front of the focal number you can add `"f/" .` before `fraction_parts[0]`. Note how the period (`.`) is used to join strings.

**Edit 2**
About the additional request posted in the comment below, this is how you can edit other outputs from your `$exif` array:

```
<dt>EXIF data:</dt>
<dd><ul>
<?php foreach ($exif as $key => $value): 
    if (($key != "Width") && ($key != "Height") && ($key !="DateTime")): ?><li><strong><?php
        if ($key == "model") { 
            echo "Camera"; 
        } elseif ($key == "ExposureTime") { 
            echo "Exposure"; 
            //$newvalue = explode("(", $value);
            //$newvalue = substr($newvalue[2], 0, -1)."s";
              $newvalue = $value . "s"; // see note 1
        } elseif ($key == "FNumber") {
            echo "Aperture";
            $fraction_parts = explode("/", $value);
            $newvalue = $fraction_parts[0] / $fraction_parts[1] // see note 2
        } elseif ($key == "ExposureProgram") { // see note 3
            echo "Exposure Program";
            $value_definitions = array(
                '2' => "Auto",
                '3' => "Aperture Priority",
                '4' => "Shutter Priority"
            );
            if( array_key_exists( $value, $value_definitions ) ) {
                $newvalue = $value_definitions[$value];
            }
        } else { 
            echo $key; 
        } ?></strong>: <?php if (!$newvalue) { echo $value; } else { echo $newvalue; $newvalue = ''; } ?></li>
    <?php endif; 
endforeach; ?>
</ul></dd></dl>
```

**Note 3**
This is a conditional that works just like the other ones. It sets the `$newvalue` variable which is used to replace the `$value` variable. However, this one will only set the `$newvalue` if the `$value` is one of the keys in the `$value_definitions` array. If `$value` matches a key in the `$value_definitions` array, `$newvalue` will be set to the value assigned to the matching key.

Comment: works perfectly!  I added the "f" in front of the aperture output by the following - $newvalue = "f" . $fraction_parts[0] / $fraction_parts[1];   This seems to work.

Comment: One more adjustment - since you made this so easy to understand, is there a way to convert a number to a word from the array?  Trying to get the ExposureProgram number outputs of 2, 3, or 4 to "Auto", "Aperture Priority", or "Shutter Priority".  I've been searching the forums but the solution all seem to be functions, and not something I can input directly to this page.

Comment: Sure, I just made an edit. Give that a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: Got it!  Just had to add a second  ")" after the  "$value_definitions ) " so it looks like this - ($value, $value_definitions))   It took a minute to figure it out - you have been a great help, much appreciated.

Comment: Nice find, thanks! I've updated the if statement. It looks like the answer has been unaccepted, can you accept it again?

Answer (score 0):

While you can directly compute the FNumber using eval(), I don't advise doing an eval() function.

In your case 28/10 is equal to 2.8 and then just append **f** on it. You can check this function that parses the value and then return the value with an f concatenated in the beginning.

```
function getfStop($fstop){

if(preg_match('/(\d+)(?:\s*)([\+\-\*\/])(?:\s*)(\d+)/', $fstop, $val) !== FALSE){
    $operator = $val[2];

    switch($operator){
        case '+':
            $p = $val[1] + $val[3];
            break;
        case '-':
            $p = $val[1] - $val[3];
            break;
        case '*':
            $p = $val[1] * $val[3];
            break;
        case '/':
            $p = $val[1] / $val[3];
            break;
    }

    return 'f'.$p;
   }
}
```

To use this function, just pass the value of FNumber e.g. `getfStop(THE_VALUE_OF_FNumber);` and that should work I believe.

Hope this helps!